# Workflows / Process Builder Limitation from an Unlimited Edition to Enterprise Edition

Tags: workflow, process-builder, limits, enterprise, unlimited

I'm moving an org from unlimited edition to Enterprise edition.

I've about 180 workflows in an object in Unlimited Edition. 
But in Enterprise edition, we can have only 50 active workflows.

We can also use Process Builders to achieve this. But, Is this limit is applicable to process builder also??

Please suggest us a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

In salesforce Enterprise Edition,

Active workflow per object limit : 50
Active flow(Process Builder) per object limit : 50

Refer below link :

1. [Automation Tool Features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_which_tool.htm&language=en_US&type=0)
2. [Process Automation Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_process.htm)

*Note : The process builder doesn’t support outbound messages. And last option is increase limits by requesting salesforce.*

Comment: Hi Tejas, I just want to know whether the limit (50) includes both Workflow & Flow?? Or We can create 50 workflows & 50 flows per object?

Comment: Yes, the limit (50) includes both Workflow & Flow.